# Cannot install php-intl on CentOS

Tags: php, centos5, yum, php5

When I run:

```
yum install php-intl
```

I get this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.as29550.net
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: mirror.as29550.net
 * updates: mirror.for.me.uk
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-intl.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6 for package: php-intl-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-intl-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Installed: php-common-5.3.14-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.14-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

I tried:

```
yum install php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
```

It says it's already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable repo remi,remove installed php-comon with 
`yum remove php-common`

and then install:

`yum install php-common php-intl`

Can you put the output from

`php -v`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're running a non-standard version of PHP, from the `remi` repository at http://rpms.famillecollet.com/el5.i386/ .  The real answer is: don't do that; if you need a more up-to-date PHP, upgrade to CentOS 6.  But that's probably not much help to you right now, though if you really don't need the updated PHP, downgrade as B14D3 advises in his answer.

Assuming you **do** need the remi PHP, then there is a `php-intl` package of the right version in the remi repository; I'm not quite sure why your `yum` isn't picking it up.  If you look in the relevant file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, is the a `priority=` statement that might be causing the base/updates repos to override the remi one?  Or is the repository disabled (`enabled=0`)?  Could you post the contents of the relevant `/etc/yum.repos.d` file?